# Angular Trackby with two lists

Tags: angular, ngfor

Is there a way to write a two ngFor lists that use trackby ... that way when an item is moved between the two lists it does not recreate the element?

my current understanding is trackby will keep elements from within a list from being recreated, i just want something that will do it across multiple lists.

Answer (score 0):

no. it is not possible with built in functionality. adding just one element to the dom tree shouldn't be a complex operation in vast majority of cases, so that optimisation is probably won't worth implemention.

Comment: it is not complex no ... however how my team has written code it has side-effects. Based on screen res it can change from one, two, or three lists of data.  And a component can open a dialog ... therefore if someone changes their screen size the dialog closes since the component is recreated.